# JAVA sort method exception : Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, exception, comparison

Sorry for this duplicate question that has been already answered on other posts. Unfortunately i did not know how to implement it on my code :

```
public int compare(Group gp1, Group gp2){   
    if (gp1.isPredOf(gp2))
        return 1;
    if (gp2.isPredOf(gp1))
        return -1;
    return 0; 
}
```

Note that if `gp1` is a predecessor of `gp2`, `gp2.isPredOf(gp1)` will return `false` and vice versa.

Could you please show me the appropriate code to avoid this exception ?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

Thank you for your help.

PS : the code of the function "isPredOf" :

```
 public boolean isPredOf(Group gp2){
  for (Operation op1 : this.operations){
        for (int i=0;i<=op1.job.operations.indexOf(op1);i++){
            if (gp2.operations.contains(op1.job.operations.get(i)))
                return true;
            }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Post the code of `isPredOf` method (or a simplified version of it)

Comment: It would also be useful to know if you've implemented `hashCode` and `equals` in your `Group` class?

Comment: This is the code of the function "isPredOf"  `code`                                             public boolean isPredOf(Group gp2){
    
        for (Operation op1 : this.operations){
            for (int i=0;i<=op1.job.operations.indexOf(op1);i++){
                if (gp2.operations.contains(op1.job.operations.get(i)))
                    return true;
                }
        }
        
        return false;
    }`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isPredOf` probably is not respecting transitivity. Check for null arguments they may creates this kind of problems.

The official documentation(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) says :

```
 The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)

The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.

Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.
```